# Subversion strange response when committing files to a repository

Tags: tortoisesvn, svn

I have been using TortoiseSVN for a 2-3 months to control my subversion. Today when I tried to commit files to a repository it showed me a strange message like this:

[alt text http://lh4.ggpht.com/_DK4gO8ys6jI/TCoFlCXZ8JI/AAAAAAAABoc/fl9q2aWPjY0/error_msg2.PNG](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_DK4gO8ys6jI/TCoFlCXZ8JI/AAAAAAAABoc/fl9q2aWPjY0/error_msg2.PNG)

When I went to the menu and selected Cleanup command it showed me this new message box:

[alt text http://lh4.ggpht.com/_DK4gO8ys6jI/TCoEws1XFDI/AAAAAAAABoY/osZwXhAXMJA/error_msg.PNG](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_DK4gO8ys6jI/TCoEws1XFDI/AAAAAAAABoY/osZwXhAXMJA/error_msg.PNG)

I have tried to release lock it says that there is nothing to unlock.
What happened with my subversion repository? Has anybody met with this problem before? How to solve it?
Besides, I had used subversion in a netbeans also to commit files without any problems. But today in a netbeans also it shows strange errors and not submitting my files to the repository.
A lot of thanks.

Comment: I would caution you against placing your subversion working folder inside a dropbox folder. You should not let other programs than Subversion itself mess with the files in those folders. It is much better if you use a central repository somewhere, and then check out locally on all the computers you need access, and don't rely on DropBox to synchronize the working folders. This will definitely lead to problems like what you're experiencing now.

Comment: @Lasse. The reason I am using Dropbox is that I need to have access to an updated working copy of my source codes from home also. How could I organize it by another way?

Comment: You should use a central repository and commit to it, so when you're at work, you change some files, you then commit to the central repository. Then at home, you first update with the latest changes from the central repository, then you work on the files, finally comitting changes back into the central repository so that they sit there when you return to work the next day. If this is not an option, then that's just too bad, using DropBox or any other background automatic file synchronization tools with Subversion working folders *will* give you problems, it is just a question of when.

Comment: If you need to have a clean repository of only working code, you should look into using a DVCS, Distributed Version Control System, like Mercurial or GIT. Then you would have *two* repositories. One with the official, stable, code, and one with the development in-flux code that you may or may not want to keep. Then you would develop in a flux repository (like the subversion central repo above), and only push changes to the stable repository once you're certain you want it there.

Comment: @Lasse. I also dreamed about central repository, but unfortunately I had no and haven't yet it. The problem is that I can't access from outside to my working servers. Therefore I can't organize central repository. What I do now, is I sync with Dropbox and commit to a repository only from the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally in this situation I tend to backup that folders files, delete the whole folder and check it out again, cleanup, then paste the files back in. Not ideal, and far from best practise I would imagine, but it works ;)

Comment: All right, but could you explain it in a step-by-step form, PLEASE. Because I don't want to loose my files that are in a repository also. And I am a dummy user in using subversion.

Comment: Well, copy the files in that folder to another folder. You can ignore the `.svn` folder. Then you want to delete the folder. After this, go to the root folder of the project, and do a `svn update` this should restore the folder with what's in the repo. Then you can paste your changed files back in. Then I would try an `svn commit`

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems when moving folders around.

Try deleting the .svn or _svn folders and doing an update.

Try deleting or renaming the entire folder and do an update, then manually re-merge your changes into it.

Of course, keep a copy of your changes so you can re-merge them.

I've heard SVN is working on getting rid of all the .svn folders and going to a single metadata file, which would probably keep this kind of problem from happening.

Comment: Yup - one must never, ever copy or move folders using the Windows functions inside a working copy: You need to export/import or rename them within SVN. I learned that the hard way :)

Comment: @Pekka. Yeah. I think this headache started once I deleted a folder that I didn't want to commit into a repository. That was a new folder which didn't exist in a repository though.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your file is not locked by another process ? I see you are using DropBox, maybe it is trying to synchronize it meanwhile ?

Comment: You're right that they are in a Dropbox folder, but I have tried to  close Dropbox and see it. But still the same error message.